# How to write unit test for asynchronous (socket) code that includes ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, sockets, tdd

I am playing around with a socket server and try to work according to the Test Driven Development pattern.

There's a working test for the socket creation method, but my test hangs due to the fact that I have a ManualResetEvent.WaitOne() so that my socket waits for a connection before creating another one.

Here's the code block to test:

```
ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public void StartListening()
{
    allDone.Reset();

    //Inform on the console that the socket is ready
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

    /* Waits for a connection and accepts it. AcceptCallback is called and the actual
     * socket passed as AsyncResult
     */
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
        listener);

    allDone.WaitOne();
}
```

And here's the test method which hangs at "networkChannel.StartListening();

```
[TestMethod]
public void NetworkChannel_IsAcceptingConnectionsAsynchronously()
{
    ITcpClient client = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITcpClient>();
    ITcpListener listener = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITcpListener>();
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IAsyncResult>();

    listener.Expect(x => x.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(asyncResult);
    listener.Expect(x => x.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult)).Return(client);

    NetworkChannel networkChannel = new NetworkChannel(listener);

    networkChannel.StartListening();
    //Some more work... fake callback etc., verfify expectations,...
}
```

If I comment all the manualresetevents, the test passes just fine but this cannot be the solution because the server tries to create duplicate sockets continuously ;-)

Any hints for me? Would be very much appreciated!

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The subtle thing here is that the `StartListening` method blocks, so my original approach won't work because we can't simply wait for it to finish before proceeding, yet we can't safely proceed until we know the `NetworkChannel` has begun listening.

The solution to this is to have the channel provide some notification when it has started up. I can think of a couple of options:

Give `NetworkChannel` the following:

```
public delegate void OnStartupComplete();
public event OnStartupComplete StartupComplete;
```

In the `StartListening` method just before `allDone.WaitOne();`:

```
if (this.StartupComplete != null)
{
    StartupComplete();
}
```

Where the event is setup via:

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
NetworkChannel networkChannel = new NetworkChannel();
networkChannel.StartupComplete += () => { resetEvent.Set(); };
networkChannel.StartListening();

resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

**Edit 2:**

This approach (and the one below) still suffers from the problem that the blocking `StartListening` call prevents anything after it from executing - like the call to `resetEvent.WaitOne();`. I think your best bet would be to have the `StartListening` run its code in another thread. Combined with the `StartupComplete` event, we should get what we want: the network channel notifying us when it is listening and the `resetEvent` ensuring that we don't do anything until it has.

The use of another thread may not be disirable from a unit testing perspective, but I think it is preferable from a design perspective: `StartListening` blocking like it does will most likely be inconvenient when we get beyond the unit tests.

To that end you could do something like this in your `StartListening` method:

```
public void StartListening()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object state) => 
    {
        allDone.Reset();

        //Inform on the console that the socket is ready
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

        /* Waits for a connection and accepts it. AcceptCallback is called and the
        * actual socket passed as AsyncResult
        */
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

        if (this.StartupComplete != null)
        {
            StartupComplete();
        }

        allDone.WaitOne();
    });
}
```

---

Alternatively you could simply modify the `StartListening` method to take a `ManualResetEvent` as an argument and simply call its `Set` method prior to `allDone.WaitOne();`. You would set this up by:

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
NetworkChannel networkChannel = new NetworkChannel();
networkChannel.StartListening(resetEvent);

resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: This is not adressing in any way testing problem. I doubt that executing threads in unit test is a good idea. In Your approach You have no idea when the channel will really start listening. So test result will not be deterministic.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura good point about the non-determinism - I have addressed this in my edit.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the point, but how does it help me to call ManualResetEvent.Set method prior to WaitOne()? This makes the test pass, but integration tests fail due to the duplicate socket problem. Would it be valid to call StartListening() in a separate thread in the unit test and fake a connection from within the unit test?

Comment: Are you wanting just one NetworkChannel for all of your tests? Keep in mind that the event we are calling Set on is different to the allDone event. The reason I have suggested this is to get around the issue where the networkChannel.StartListening method blocks and prevents the subsequent code from running.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your suggestions. Now I see who you approached the issue. The StartupComplete even fires off right after the BeginAcceptTcpClient call in NetworkChannel. But this does not "motivate" the unit test to step over "networkChannel.StartListening()". I think I would have to put this into a separate thread what is not the sense behind unit testing. How about passing the listener through the resetEvent and validate that it indicates "open" state?

Comment: Nick, good catch with the issues down the road if for some reason the listener cannot be started and blocks the program as a result. Implemented it as suggested and works fine. Looking forward to some integration tests :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what you want to test excactly?

If the test just expects the method `StartListening` to call `listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient`, then the easiest solution would be to inject and mock your synchronization object (`ManualResetEvent`) in your SUT like you done with the listener with a non blocking mock.

When you want to test the blocking, you have to start another thread in your test *before* calling `listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient` which signals the ManualResetEvent after some *safe* wait time - lets say two seconds - but that might even be not enough, so your testresult might not be deterministic as Grzegorz commented.

Threads and unit testing can get somewhat complicated.